# Control pdf document in flex

Tags: pdf, apache-flex

How can I hide the Adobe Reader toolbar when displaying a PDF in the adobe flex Web Browser control?

Example in the IRCTC website the ticket showed in PDF format ,we only Print the PDF.Same format I want.

Please forwarding your answers.

Comment: is it any coding related stuff ?update your post and elaborate problem if any code regarding it . if not will be closed as off-topic soon enough

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default page mode for the PDF to fullscreen.
[image: Page Mode description in PDF reference]